# MySQL Multiple column joins with more than one table references

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am using `MySQL 5.6.17`.

I have a `table` that contains the master entries of titles let us say it `Master_titles`. It contains columns `id int primary key auto-increment`, `title varchar(255)`. The data is as shown below :

```
id     title
1      Item one
2      Item two
3      Item three
4      Item five 
6      Item six
7      Item seven
8      Item eight
9      Item nine
10     Item ten
```

There is another table named `routines` that is `self-referencing table` contains the `records with parent-child relationship`. The columns are `id int primary key auto-increment`, `master_title_id int foreign key references id of Master_titles`, `type varchar(2)`, `parent int foreign key referencing id of routines` itself. The data is as below :

```
id     master_title_id     type     parent 
1      1                   G        null
2      2                   Q        1
3      3                   A        2
4      4                   A        2 
5      5                   Q        1
6      6                   A        5
7      8                   A        5
8      2                   G        null 
9      5                   Q        8
10     7                   A        9
11     8                   A        9
12     9                   A        9
```

And another table let us say `data`, that contains columns as `id int primary key auto-increment`, `routine_id int foreign key references id of routines`, `group id int`, `question_id int`, `answer id int`. Here, all of the records of columns i.e. `group_id`, `question_id`, `answer_id` will be the `id` of `routines` table. The data is as below :

```
id     routine_id     group_id     question_id     answer_id
1      2              1            2               4
2      5              1            5               6
3      9              8            9               11
4      5              1            5               7
5      2              1            2               7
3      9              8            9               10
```

Now, I want a `query` that fetches `titles` for the columns `group_id`, `question_id` and `answer_id` from `master_titles` table.

I can do it using `sub-query` but what is most efficient way to fetch the records without overheads?

The query i.e. working but I don't prefer to be used is as below :

```
SELECT  data.created_at,
(SELECT Master_titles.title FROM `Master_titles` LEFT JOIN routines ON Master_titles.id = routines.master_title_id LEFT JOIN data ON routines.id = data.group_id WHERE data.id = data.`id`) AS Group,
(SELECT Master_titles.title FROM `Master_titles` LEFT JOIN routines ON Master_titles.id = routines.master_title_id LEFT JOIN data ON routines.id = data.question_id WHERE data.id = data.`id`) AS Question,
(SELECT Master_titles.title FROM `Master_titles` LEFT JOIN routines ON Master_titles.id = routines.master_title_id LEFT JOIN data ON routines.id = data.answer_id WHERE data.id = data.`id`) AS Answer
FROM data;
```

Comment: Please post your effort towards attaining result (query using subquery). I'm not sure what you meant by `Here, all of the records of columns i.e. group_id, question_id, answer_id will be the id of routines table. `. Do you mean that all of those columns in table `data` (in spite of id) actually refer to `routines.id` ?

Comment: can you provide the sub-query solution? because, I see only direct joins required. Is there any duplication when joining directly?

Comment: @ConsiderMe Yes, all the columns contains the ids that are id of routines table. But only routine_id is a foreign key, not others.

Comment: @JoseTuttu Yes,  the subquery contains the duplications. Let me edit the question with posting it, but I don't think it is an efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment stating, that all the columns containing ids in table `data` are actually `ids` of `routines` table you need to perform joins to get title for every column by going through the path that is `routines > master_titles`.

```
SELECT 
    d.id,
    d.routine_id,
    mgroup.title group,
    mquestion.title question,
    manswer.title answer
FROM
    data d
    LEFT JOIN routines r1 ON ( d.group_id = r.id )
    LEFT JOIN master_titles mgroup ON ( r1.master_title_id = m.id )
    LEFT JOIN routines r2 ON ( d.question_id = r.id )
    LEFT JOIN master_titles mquestion ON ( r2.master_title_id = m.id )
    LEFT JOIN routines r3 ON ( d.answer_id = r.id )
    LEFT JOIN master_titles manswer ON ( r3.master_title_id = m.id )
```

Don't worry about amount of joins (never calculate cost of a query by size of it in terms of lines).

I suggest following index to speed up: routines(master_title_id).

Also, take under consideration (can't estimate your environment) indexes on group_id, question_id and answer_id columns.

You know best whether or not it is going to help you with performance and not hurt your writes/space unprofitably at the same time.

Comment: Is it possible to provide same alias name for multiple joins? Also, from dataset provided there is no need of left join, inner join will be much better.

Comment: @JoseTuttu good point, it is obviously not, I haven't checked the code so I forgot about it. I decided to go with `LEFT JOIN`s in case of no match (there are no references on those columns so an insert typo could disqualify a record from output).

Comment: Oh, I didnt see your reply, any way, I posted the same as another answer.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks, accepted and +1 for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small change from "Consider Me" answer.

```
SELECT 
    d.id,
    d.routine_id,
    mgroup.title group,
    mquestion.title question,
    manswer.title answer
FROM
    data d
    JOIN routines r1 ON ( d.group_id = r.id )
    JOIN master_titles mgroup ON ( r1.master_title_id = m.id )
    JOIN routines r2 ON ( d.question_id = r.id )
    JOIN master_titles mquestion ON ( r2.master_title_id = m.id )
    JOIN routines r3 ON ( d.answer_id = r.id )
    JOIN master_titles manswer ON ( r3.master_title_id = m.id )
```

Inner join should be better since  `group_id`, `question_id` and `answer_id` are not defined as nullable in `data` table. But since there is no foreign key relationship, there can be instances of missing rows if there are values which are not present in routines table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. +1 for resolving the bug in @Consider Me's answer. However, left joins are working fine for me, not inner joins hence I cannot accept this as answer but up vote for your kind help.

Answer (score -1):

You can do multiple joins to the same table, by aliasing the table being joined.

```
SELECT data.id, gm.title AS gm_title, qm.title AS qm_title, am.title AS am_title 

JOIN routines AS gr
ON gr.id = data.group_id    
JOIN master_titles AS gm 
ON gm.id = gr.master_title_id 

JOIN routines AS qr
ON qr.id = data.question_id
JOIN master_titles AS qm
ON qm.id = qr.master_title_id

JOIN routines AS ar
ON ar.id = data.answer_id
JOIN master_titles AS am
ON am.id = ar.master_title_id

FROM data
```

Comment: Can you please post a full query?

Comment: @spikejd you might want to consider reviewing your syntax first. Your answer also doesn't involve connecting table that is `routines` in this case.